# How to take subarray from 2d Boost.MultiArray?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I am working on a program where I need to use 2d Boost.MultiArray. I managed to initialize it and fill it with data. But I don't understand how to take subarray of size `i`,`j` if multiarray is of size `m`,`n`. Where `i<=m` and `j<=n`. Can anyone help me?
Code:

```cpp
matrix_type matrix(boost::extents[width][height]);
        read_matrix_from_file(file_content, matrix);
for (int rank = 1; rank < workers; rank++) {
            auto subarray_size = (rest > 0) ? lines_per_worker + 1 : lines_per_worker;
            rest--;

            typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;


            size_t finish_line = subarray_size + bias - 1;
            finish_line = (finish_line==bias)? finish_line+1:finish_line;


            matrix_type::array_view<2>::type
                    current_process_batch = matrix[boost::indices[range(bias, subarray_size + bias - 1)][range(0, width)]];
}
```

Comment: It's polite to show some code to show what you have, so others don't have to imagine the code just so they can come up with an answer.

Comment: I added my current code, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_generators

> Boost.MultiArray provides the facilities for creating a sub-view of an
>   already existing array component. It allows you to create a sub-view
>   that retains the same number of dimensions as the original array or
>   one that has less dimensions than the original as well.
>
> **Sub-view
>   creation occurs by placing a call to operator[], passing it an
>   index_gen type**. The index_gen is populated by passing index_range
>   objects to its operator[]. The index_range and index_gen types are
>   defined in the multi_array_types namespace and as nested members of
>   every array type. Similar to boost::extents, the library by default
>   constructs the object boost::indices. You can suppress this object by
>   defining BOOST_MULTI_ARRAY_NO_GENERATORS before including the library
>   header. A simple sub-view creation example follows.

Sample:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88dc1741dd02997a)**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Ma>
auto dump(Ma const& r) -> std::enable_if_t<1 == Ma::dimensionality> {
    for (auto c: r)
        std::cout << " " << c;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <typename Ma>
auto dump(Ma const& ma) -> std::enable_if_t<2 == Ma::dimensionality> {
    for (auto const& r: ma)
        dump(r);
}

int main() {using range = boost::multi_array_types::index_range;
    using boost::extents;
    using boost::indices;

    auto mn = extents[7][4];
    boost::multi_array<int, 2> ma(mn);

    // fill with numbers from 10..37
    std::iota(ma.data(), ma.data() + ma.num_elements(), 10);

    dump(ma);

    std::cout << "Slice [3..5][1..3]\n";
    dump(ma[ indices[range(3,5)][range(1,3)] ]);

    std::cout << "Slice [2..4][2..3]\n";
    dump(ma[ indices[range(2,4)][range(2,3)] ]);

    std::cout << "Slice [1,3,5][2..3]\n";
    dump(ma[ indices[range(1,7,2)][range(2,3)] ]);

    std::cout << "Degenerate views (reduced dimensionality):\n";
    std::cout << "Slice [1,3,5][2]\n";
    dump(ma[ indices[range(1,7,2)][2] ]);

    std::cout << "Slice [0][1,3]\n";
    dump(ma[ indices[0][range(1,4,2)] ]);
}
```

Prints

```
 10 11 12 13
 14 15 16 17
 18 19 20 21
 22 23 24 25
 26 27 28 29
 30 31 32 33
 34 35 36 37
Slice [3..5][1..3]
 23 24
 27 28
Slice [2..4][2..3]
 20
 24
Slice [1,3,5][2..3]
 16
 24
 32
Degenerate views (reduced dimensionality):
Slice [1,3,5][2]
 16 24 32
Slice [0][1,3]
 11 13
```

## UPDATE

Re. Comment:

if you want to avoid the degenerate dimensions, here's how:

**Live On Coliru**

```
std::cout << "Degenerate views (reduced dimensionality):\n";
std::cout << "Slice [1,3,5][2]\n";
dump(ma[ indices[range(1,7,2)][2] ]);

std::cout << "Slice [0][1,3]\n";
dump(ma[ indices[0][range(1,4,2)] ]);

// RE: Comment
std::cout << "NON-Degenerate views (reduced dimensionality):\n";
std::cout << "Slice [1,3,5][2]\n";
dump(ma[ indices[range(1,7,2)][range(2,3)] ]);

std::cout << "Slice [0][1,3]\n";
dump(ma[ indices[range(0,1)][range(1,4,2)] ]);
```

Prints

```
Degenerate views (reduced dimensionality):
Slice [1,3,5][2]
 16 24 32
Slice [0][1,3]
 11 13
NON-Degenerate views (reduced dimensionality):
Slice [1,3,5][2]
 16
 24
 32
Slice [0][1,3]
 11 13
```

Basically, don't use literals `[i][j]` but `[range(i,i+1)][range(j,j+1)]`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how to take only one line from 2d array and make this variable to be f the same type as several lines subarrays?

Comment: Ah. So you desperately needed to be more precise with the question. And I - accidentally - touched on it in the answer: you just need to avoid degenerate dimensions: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bacdf2e0367d125a

Comment: Added an **UPDATE** to the answer. Basically, don't use literals `[i][j]` but `[range(i,i+1)][range(j,j+1)]`